# Access data from another app

Tags: android

Is it possible to access the files in the data folder of another app?
The folder i want to access is:

```
/data/data/com.example.app/files/
```

From within my app.

Comment: You could on a rooted phone if your app is granted permission by `SU`.

Comment: @Torcellite an app itself can't be granted root by su, only native helpers can be.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Thanks for clearing my misconception, but what is a native helper?

Comment: A command line program, such as cat or echo or rm, or one you write yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access files from internal app folder from another app. Only on rooted phone, but I think it's not acceptable for you.

You can use:

1) Files on SD card

2) Content providers - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Untrue.  You can do so on an unrooted device if the owning app sets file permissions to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a common folder for both apps other than data folder of an app.

Comment: The only portable-across-versions other option is the external storage.  But a folder in the private storage of an app can be shared if the owning app wishes to enable the necessary permission (mode) bits.